# Displying Image using URI not working on Android Q

Tags: java, android, uri, android-10.0

In my app, I'm trying to display all images from a specific folder in the gallery, the code below works fine on **Android O**, but when I test it in **Android Q (API 29)**, nothing displayed.

```
public static File[] getAllImages(Activity activity) {
        String[] r3 = new String[2];
        int i = 0;
        r3[0] = "_data";
        r3[1] = "_id";
        Cursor query = activity.getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, r3, null, null, "datetaken DESC");
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        while (i < query.getCount()) {
            query.moveToPosition(i);
            int columnIndex = query.getColumnIndex("_data");
            if (query.getString(columnIndex).contains("/Pictures/FolderName")) {
                arrayList.add(new File(query.getString(columnIndex)));
            }
            i++;
        }
        return (File[]) arrayList.toArray(new File[arrayList.size()]);
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

```
  private ArrayList<Photo> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
    ArrayList<Photo> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] r3 = new String[2];
    int i = 0;
    r3[0] = "_data";
    r3[1] = "_id";
    Cursor query = activity.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, r3, null, null, "datetaken DESC");
    while (i < query.getCount()) {
        query.moveToPosition(i);
        int columnIndex = query.getColumnIndex("_id");
        listOfAllImages.add(new Photo("", ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columnIndex)));
        i++;
    }
    return listOfAllImages;
}
```

The `arrayList` photo, full with `URIs`, I have checked it with `photo.size()`

Answer (score 2):

> int columnIndex = query.getColumnIndex("_data");

`DATA` is:

- Unavailable on Android Q and higher
- Unreliable on prior versions of Android (e.g., may point to a file that you do not have rights to access)

In terms of eventually using these images:

- Get the `_id` column from your `Cursor`
- Pass that to `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`, along with your root `Uri` (`Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`)

`ContentUris.withAppendedId()` gives you a `Uri` that you can use with your favorite image-loading library to display the image.

In terms of your filtering logic:

- Include `MediaStore.Image.Media.RELATIVE_PATH` in your query
- Examine that column to see if it references your name, using the same algorithm that you used when you put the image into the `MediaStore` in the first place

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please check my update post

Comment: @pic: Please do not edit a question and completely replace what you had. Now, somebody encountering this question and my answer has to hunt through revision history to see the actual question that I answered. In terms of your problem, what you have here seems OK, so perhaps the issue is in how you are using the `Photo` objects.